# How to modify Scaffold widget for the whole app

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a big app and there's multi files with same scaffold tap action to hide the keyboard.

```
 Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
            },
            child: Container(
                ///Textfields
            ),
          ),
        ),
    );
```

Is there way to edit Scaffold widget for the whole app?

Comment: I think the shortcut that you're looking for is:

Ctrl+Shift+R on Windows and Linux/Ubuntu

Cmd+Shift+R on Mac OS X

Comment: @towhid I knew it but I want to make my code less

Comment: @shuaib please check the answer below

Comment: You can add GestureDetector to your app widget instead of scaffold which should work on all the pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

short answer, you can not customize your scaffold for the whole app because each scaffold has its own body, but you can customize the theme of the app such as the text colour or the font for the whole app on the main screen using the materialApp widget.

-If you are willing to make something fixed in the whole app like the same app bar or the navbar for the whole app that's possible and you have to create a separate screen for it.
-or if you are using a customized widget a lot, Flutter let you extract it, give it a name and use it again without rewriting the whole code again but by just writing the name you chose for it

Answer (score 2):

In that case you can create your custom scaffold wrapper.

```
class ScaffoldWrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  const ScaffoldWrapper({Key? key, required this.child}) : super(key: key);

  final Widget child;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () => FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode()),
          child: child,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now you can replace all occurrence of your mentioned code block with this..

```
ScaffoldWrapper(child: Container()); // your widget contents
```